# How can I store the selected element in a dropdown menu using a Selenium/Python script?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to store the currently selected value in a dropdown menu to a variable, but I can't find the correct way to do so in Python. I'm able to print the whole list by selecting the element and typing `print element.text`, but I'd like to be able to store the selected element.

Here is the html of the dropdown menu.

```
<select id="offer.sections.edit.jobHighlights.permanentLocationId" onchange="OWF_synchronizeQualifiedRelocationPackages(); OWF_selectCompanyBySelectedLocation()" onblur="OWF_showChangedControl(this)" name="offer.permanentLocationId">
    <option value=""/>
    <option value="AE-DXB-DIC9">AE-DXB-DIC9: Dubai, United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="AE-HOME-35819">AE-HOME-35819: Home-Gawdat, Dubai, UAE</option>
    <option value="AR-BUE-ALI">AR-BUE-ALI: Buenos Aires, Argentina</option>
    <option value="AR-REMOTE-GEN">AR-REMOTE-GEN: Argentina - Remote</option>
    <option value="AT-REMOTE-GEN">AT-REMOTE-GEN: Austria - Remote</option>
    <option value="AT-VIE-GRA">AT-VIE-GRA: Vienna, Austria</option>
    <option value="AU-HOME-22038">AU-HOME-22038: Home-Whitlow, Carlton, AU</option>
    <option value="AU-HOME-23104">AU-HOME-23104: Home-Miller, Brunswick, AU</option>
    <option value="AU-HOME-49114">AU-HOME-49114: Home-Whiteman, Brighton East, AU</option>
    <option value="AU-REMOTE-GEN">AU-REMOTE-GEN: Australia - Remote</option>
    <option value="AU-SYD-PIR">AU-SYD-PIR: Sydney, Australia</option>
    <option value="BA-REMOTE-GEN">BA-REMOTE-GEN: Bosnia and Herzegovina - Remote</option>
    <option value="BE-BRU-ETT">BE-BRU-ETT: Brussels, Belgium</option>
    <option value="BE-GHL-DAT1">BE-GHL-DAT1: Data Center, Ghlin, Belgium</option>
    <option value="BE-REMOTE-GEN">BE-REMOTE-GEN: Belgium - Remote</option>
    <option value="BG-REMOTE-GEN">BG-REMOTE-GEN: Bulgaria - Remote</option>
    <option value="BR-BAR-DAT1">BR-BAR-DAT1: Barueri, Brazil</option>
    <option value="BR-BHZ-THT" selected="selected">BR-BHZ-THT: Belo Horizonte, Brazil</option>
    <option value="BR-REMOTE-GEN">BR-REMOTE-GEN: Brazil - Remote</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will get you the selected option:

```
option = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("offer.sections.edit.jobHighlights.permanentLocationId")).first_selected_option
```